# django 1.9.9 cannot import name HAS_GEOIP

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.9.9. I would like to use django-tracking module in my project. However, when I try to use django-tracking I encounter the following error message:

```html
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tracking/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.utils import HAS_GEOIP
ImportError: cannot import name HAS_GEOIP
sTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tracking/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.utils import HAS_GEOIP
ImportError: cannot import name HAS_GEOIP
```

GeoIP module is properly installed. What I can see that django is looking foro HAS_GEOIP in django.contrib.gis.utils, but instead it should look in django.contrib.gis.geoip. How do I tell django 1.9.9 to use django.contrib.gis.geoip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do upgrade by `django-tracking` using `develop` branch. Otherwise downgrade `django`

```
pip install git+https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking.git@develop
```

Comment: I wouldn't downgrade django, but this solves the problems. Thumbs up!!!